# How to remove preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to deactivate the form temporarily and display a confirmation box whether the data wants to be sent or not, but I have problems when I want to activate the form again.

Code to deactivate form :

```
var statusForm = true;
$("form.form-update").submit((e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("form.form-update input").each((key, element) => {
        if (element.value == "") {
            statusForm = false;
        }
    });
    if (statusForm == false) {
        alert("Data is invalid!");
    }
    else{
        // Show the popup
        $(".confirm-notification").show();
    }
})
```

Code when "yes" button is clicked :

```
// When "yes" button click
$(".confirm-notification-yes").click(()=>{
    // Code to remove preventDefault() on $("form.form-update")
})
```

How to remove preventDefault() on $("form.form-update")?

[**Problem solved**]
Problem was solved with combined the unbind() and submit() method. So the code became :

```
$(".confirm-notification-yes").click(()=>{
    $("form.form-update").unbind('submit');
    $("form.form-update").submit();
})
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Just remove the line of code? You can keep preventDefault and then hide the form (display: none) and then show the confirmation box.

Comment: because I want to submit form when the "yes" button on confirmation was clicked. i confused to submit that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On "Yes", submit the form:

```js
$(".confirm-notification-yes").click(()=>{
    $("form.form-update").submit();
})
```

Now, let's fix the first part.  I suppose submission is started through a button.  You put your code in that button, not the submit event.

```
$("btn-that-initiates-submission").click(() => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let missingValue = false;
    $("form.form-update input").each((key, element) => {
        if (element.value === "") {
            missingValue = true;
        }
    });
    if (missingValue) {
        alert("There's missing data in the form.");
    }
    else {
        $("confirm-notification").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your advice brother. it worked when i combined the unbind() with submit() method.

Answer (score 0):

do it like that

```
// When "yes" button click
$(".confirm-notification-yes").click(()=>{
// Code to remove preventDefault() on $("form.form-update")
 $("form.form-update").unbind('submit').click();
 })
```